# how to auto increment id in RaectjS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to auto increment id number so I can add multiple objects to my database

```
        description : '' ,
        expensedate : new Date(),
        id: '104',
        location : '',
        category : {id:1 , name:'Travel'}
    };

    
    constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state = { 
        isLoading :false,
        Categories:[],
        Expsenses : [],
        date :new Date(),
        item : this.emptyItem
       }
```

I tried using function

```
      this.setState(prevState => {
        if (prevState.item.id > 0) {
          return {
            id: prevState.item.id + 1
          }
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
```

but it did not work, any help on what should I do?

Comment: You could store the current id as the highest/max id and increment that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.setState(prevState => {
  if (Number(prevState.item.id) > 0) {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      item : {
        ...prevState.item,
        id: String(Number(prevState.item.id) + 1)
      }
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Check the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Simple React.js Increment / Decrement.
link: https://codepen.io/ajcbrown820/pen/eZdWaj

```js
var Increment = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    };
  },

  increment: function() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  },
  
  decrement: function(){
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter - 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <div id='counter'>{this.state.counter}</div> 
      <button onClick = {this.increment}> Add 1 </button> 
      <button onClick = {this.decrement}> Minus 1 </button> 
     </div>
  }
});

React.render(<Increment />, document.getElementById('mount'))
```

```css
#mount{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#counter{
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='mount'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```